# Prevent list containing an image from breaking

Tags: html, css, wordpress, list

I have the following lay-out on my website: [List of products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL0wb.png)

This is actually the Woocommerce product list which is an unordered list.

The HTML of the list looks something like this:

```
<div class="widget widget_woocommerce_ndbproducts">
  <ul class="product_list_widget">                  
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.slagerijrudi.be/product/broodje-ham/" title="Broodje Ham">
      <img src="//www.slagerijrudi.be/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/images/placeholder.png" alt="Placeholder" width="180" class="woocommerce-placeholder wp-post-image" height="180">Broodje Ham</a>
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>
        2,85
      </span>
    </li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In order to have this list in 4 columns on desktop, I've added the following CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
  .four-columns ul.product_list_widget {
      -moz-column-count: 4;
      -moz-column-gap: 20px;
      -webkit-column-count: 4;
      -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
      column-count: 4;
      column-gap: 20px;
  }
}
```

However, as you can see by the red arrows in my screenshot, the `<li>` item gets a line break, which is not desired as the picture & price/text are no longer together this way.

Any ideas on how to prevent this? 
If you want to test: this is [the link](https://www.slagerijrudi.be/broodjes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `page-break-inside: avoid` and `break-inside: avoid` (has greater browser support) to the `li` items, which then prevent breaking inside those elements:

```
ul.cart_list li,
ul.product_list_widget li,
.widget_product_categories li {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit, new solution:

Now that I've had a look at it live, because each `<li>` other than the first one has a padding-top of 15px, the padding is what's pushing your second column down. If you can situate it so that the top item in every column doesn't have a padding-top, it should resolve your problem without needing anything extra and then you wouldn't have to worry about solving the line breaking itself. It's more of a padding/height issue than a line-break issue.

A `min-height` on your `<ul>` could also be a potential solution, but if you want the items to align better, solving the padding problem would be preferred.